# django redirect no reverse match error

Tags: python, django, redirect

Here is my main project timecapture/urls.py  content:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from . import views


urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^login/$',views.auth_login,name='auth_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$',views.auth_logout,name='auth_logout'),
    url(r'^timesheet/',include('timesheet.urls'),name='timesheet')
]
```

And here is an app inside main project timesheet/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . import views

urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^$',views.index),
]
```

I am unable to redirect to 'timesheet' url. I am using the following command:

```
return redirect('timesheet')
```

But this is working:

```
return redirect('/timesheet/')
```

Exact error is `enter code here

```
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'timesheet' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Btw I am using latest django 1.9.2 with python 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a URL named "timesheet". You've got an include with that name, but not the views.

Remove `name='timesheet'` from the include in the main urls.py, and add it instead to the index url in timesheet/urls.py.

Comment: Or he can add name to included urls like `url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),`, so code will be `redirect('timesheet:index')`

Comment: @tug thats a good way to do it. I am such a newbie. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @tug The `name` parameter to `url()` does not set a namespace. You need the `namespace` parameter to `include()` for that.

Comment: @knbk yeah, you are absolutely right, code for root urlpatterns for my comment is `url(r'^timesheet/',include('timesheet.urls', namespace='timesheet'))`